# Redux Submitting a form from Presentation Component to Container Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using a simple Login Form and i have LoginContainer (Container Component ) and Login (presentation component) and i am trying to submit the form and access the data in the Container Component.

Here is the code i have

Login.js:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login jumbotron center-block">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form role="form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                      <input type="text"  className="form-control" ref="username" placeholder="Username" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" className="form-control" ref="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default" onClick={()=>{this.props.login(this.refs.username,this.refs.password)}}>Submit</button>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the container component is:

```
class LoginContainer extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <Login login={this.loginUser}/>
          </div>  

        );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return state;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return{
        login : (username,password) => {
               console.log('mapDispatchToProps : username=['+username+'] password=['+password+']');
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

The above code doesn't work as in the event handler for the submit i cannot access this.refs

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: refs is not defined
```

I don't want to maintain the state of Login Component. I can easily create  state with username and password in Login and use setState with onclick or onchange on username and password controls.

Is there way i can send the data of form elements from Presentation component to Container component with a form submit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make event handling methods in Login.js file and bind them to the component context using bind function in the constructor.

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }

    login() {
        this.props.login(this.refs.username,this.refs.password)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login jumbotron center-block">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form role="form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                      <input type="text"  className="form-control" ref="username" placeholder="Username" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" className="form-control" ref="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.login}>Submit</button>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This way you dont maintain state of Logic component, you simply use props passed from the container.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How ever when i tried it i am getting the error: **Login.js?9830:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined** . How ever when i used the following it worked. **this.loginCaller = () =>  this.longinCaller();**   I have used bind in my other projects and it worked in all my constructors. not sure why it is erroring out here. Any way thanks for pointing out.

Comment: bind() worked as expected. Sorry there was a typo in my code ... Aah..Thanks